# Flex: FileReference and Image unhandled IOErrorEvent

Tags: apache-flex, image, filereference, ioerror

The following code shows a button that allows you to select a file (should be an image) and display it into an image component. When I select an invalid image (e.g. unsupported image type, a word document), I get the following error:

**"Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type."**

I know I can pass a FileFilter to the FileReference:browse call, but that's beyond the point. My question is... **I want to handle the IOErrorEvent myself, what event listener am I missing?**

```
private var file:FileReference = new FileReference();

private function onBrowse():void {
    file.browse(null);
    file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, handleFileSelect);
    file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleFileComplete);
    file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleFileIoError);
}

private function handleFileSelect(event:Event):void {
    file.load();
}

private function handleFileComplete(event:Event):void {
    myImage.source = file.data;
}

private function handleFileIoError(event:Event):void {
    Alert.show("handleFileIoError");
}

private function handleImageIoError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
    Alert.show("handleImageIoError");
}

<mx:Button click="onBrowse()" label="Browse"/>
<mx:Image id="myImage" width="100" height="100" ioError="handleImageIoError(event)"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is a bug from Flex SDK. Take a look on SWFLoader, method loadContent. It does not have a handler for errors for several cases (your included). The bug is fixed in SDK 3.4 , so it maybe a good idea to do an update.